# Terraform: Error: timeout waiting for an available IP address

Tags: terraform, vsphere, vcenter, terraform-provider-vsphere

I am new to Terraform and I am tying to create a VM using terraform. Below is my code.
I want to clone a VM and don't want to give an IP. The VM gets created in vSphere but terraform kept on waiting for IP. Is there any way I can stop terraform to stop waiting for an ip?

Below is my code..

```
provider "vsphere" {
  user                 = var.vsphere_user
  password             = var.vsphere_pass
  vsphere_server       = var.vsphere_server
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}

#Creating the data for resource

data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
  name = var.vsphere_datacenter
}

data "vsphere_datastore_cluster" "datastore_cluster" {
  name          = var.datastore_cluster
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name          = var.vsphere_datastore
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

data "vsphere_resource_pool" "pool" {
  name = "RHEL IMAGES"
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

data "vsphere_network" "network" {
  name          = var.network
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template" {
  name          = var.vmtemp
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  #   count = var.instances
  name             = var.vmname
  num_cpus         = var.cpu_number
  memory           = var.ram_size
  resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id
  guest_id         = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.guest_id

  network_interface {
    network_id = data.vsphere_network.network.id
    adapter_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.network_interface_types[0]

  }

  disk {
    label = "disk0"
    size  = 140
  }

  clone {
    template_uuid = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id

    customize {
      linux_options {

        host_name = var.vmname
        domain    = "development.test"
      }

       network_interface {
         ipv4_address = ""
         ipv4_netmask = 0
       }
    }

  }
}
```

I have tried the below options and it doesn't work.. Can anyone please help me on this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot to add the below option which i have tried and no luck.. wait_for_guest_ip_timeout = 0
wait_for_guest_net_timeout = -1

Comment: i have same issue with debian 11, but don't have with debian 10.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by changing the below parameter.

```
wait_for_guest_net_timeout = 0
```